# Can't change <p> tag in the_content using string replace

Tags: php, wordpress

I am struggling to get a simple string replace to work in wordpress the_content function.

```
<?php 

    $phrase = the_content();
    $find = '<p>';
    $replace = '<p style="text-align: left; font-family: Georgia, Times, serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px; color: #1b3d52; font-weight: normal; margin: 15px 0px; font-style: italic;">';

    $newphrase = str_replace($find, $replace, $phrase);

    echo $newphrase;

?>
```

It just seems to echoing `<p>` still.

Instead of `<p style="text-align: left; font-family: Georgia, Times, serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px; color: #1b3d52; font-weight: normal; margin: 15px 0px; font-style: italic;">`

Comment: And you're sure there no spaces inside the tag?

Comment: consider using a DOM Parser: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `apply_filters('the_content')` to have Wordpress newlines with paragraphs.

```
<?php 

    $phrase = get_the_content();
    // This is where wordpress filters the content text and adds paragraphs
    $phrase = apply_filters('the_content', $phrase);
    $replace = '<p style="text-align: left; font-family: Georgia, Times, serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px; color: #1b3d52; font-weight: normal; margin: 15px 0px; font-style: italic;">';

    echo str_replace('<p>', $replace, $phrase);

?>
```

See the codex entry for [the_content](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content). Its in the alternative usage section.

Comment: I love you man! Can see why it wasn't working now and you've totally fixed. Thank you so much!!!!!

Comment: No problem, a lot of the time the Wordpress codex can be either confusing or just wrong and digging into the source helps a lot.

Answer (score 3):

the_content does not return the content but it echoes the content.

If you want to get the content in the variable you have to use

> $phrase = get_the_content()

You should run this inside a loop just like the_content()

Comment: Thanks, but if I use `get_the_content()` - it does not output my content in paragraph tags like `the_content()` does. And therefor has nothing to find and replace.

Comment: I need to append an inline style to my <p> tags.

Comment: Yes, but Prathik is right; if you use the_content(), you are not placing the content value in $phrase, you are actually directly echoing it. Anyway, your solution is to use apply_filters() as mentioned by papirtiger